# how to make multiple products apear as a single one in opencart

Tags: php, javascript, opencart

hi there i was writing a module for opencart that let's the user chose from some

products(mother board, graphical card, processor ...)

in a wizard style that for every choice i retreive the "id" of the selected product

but calling a

```
 addtocart(id);
```

for every product will make them apear as a list of products

but i want to make them added to the cart as a single product called

"costimized pc"

and make the order treat them as a single product as well

any idea about how or where should i start are welcome

Comment: any idea will be very helpfull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really something simple to achieve, since OpenCart is designed as a shopping cart for single item products. Your best solution would be to use options instead for a single product, and perhaps change it so that they display in a better fashion on your product page

Comment: i know it is not simple and i want to have any idea about what i can do , for now all i was thinking of is to change the cart files in system/

Comment: As I've said, your best option would be to use options instead of products grouped. That is essentially what options are for

Comment: i have a module that have costum groups of products and display them on after other in steps(wizard) in the end i want to add them to the cart a single product(a costume pc) and i cant use options cuz i have to make them displayed in the admin area(order) as a group of products so,the admin user can know when someone want him to build a pc with thos specific products 
and products are not specified manually they are from theire original groups(graphical card,mother board, stuff...)

Answer (score 0):

Because there is simply ne easy way to do this i think the best way to do so is :

->Copy the Cart system and rename it to Build

->Remove the Options from the getProduct() function

->rewrite the total calcultion to calculate every total of a group of products as a single product

->in the admin add another order page that handle the products groups

->in the add to cart function in common.js add a function that sends the products as a string of joined IDs

->add to the cart common/cart.tpl the needed variable to display the groups of products as a single products and the price of them and rewrite the removeCart() function;

Answer (score 0):

Use Product as Group. Options as Products withing the group. Simple as that. :)